# %p for percent in stacked graph with jquery.flot.tooltip is not working

Tags: jquery, flot, flot.tooltip

I am using jquery.flot.js (v 1.1) for graphs and for tooltip jquery.flot.tooltip.js (version: 0.6.7)

I wanted to show percentage area covered by each stack in stacked graph. 
I have tried it using %p. 
But it's not working, it return "%p" in tooltip.
Code snippet:

```
tooltip: true,
tooltipOpts: {
  content: "%s : %y : %p.1%"
}
```

My graph is-

[image]

Could any one help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%p` only if you also use pie charts plugin http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-pie/index.html, that placeholder was introduced only to support that plugin. I see that is not clear in the documentation.

In your case you need to count percentage value by yourself. You may use callback function for that. The format is `function(label, xval, yval, flotItem)` and must return a string in correct format (needed by tooltip).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I have tried %p also but it doesn't work, don't know why its not working.

I can't use function because, I wanted to show the percentage area covered by each stack in bar.
ex: last bar height = 78
then percent value of green stack should be (64/78)*100 = 82

Comment: In the function i cant access value of other stack in the same bar.
Is that accessible ?

Comment: Once again, `%p` works only with pie charts. You don't have pie chart so it won't work. I don't know if you can access value of other stacks, check i.e. what you get in `flotItem` object. But you also have access to raw data that you pass to flot, so you could  use them (?). Don't rely only on tooltip plugin, use data that you have.